# Port Map-ing to ground in VHDL

Tags: mapping, port, vhdl

I am new to VHDL and having an issue trying to port map to ground.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

---- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
---- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity msPC4 is
    Port ( b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
           a : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              co : out STD_LOGIC);
end msPC4;

architecture Structure of msPC4 is

    component msdff4
        Port ( d : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
                 clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
                 q : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
    end component;

    component msFA4bit
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           ci : in  STD_LOGIC;
           s : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           co : out  STD_LOGIC);
    end component;

    component ms21mux4
    Port ( d1 : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           d0 : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           s : in  STD_LOGIC;
           z : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
    end component;

    signal w0, w1, w2, w3: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    signal w4 : STD_LOGIC;


w4 <= '0';
w3 <= '0000';

begin
gmsPC4g1: msdff4 port map (w1,clk,w2);
gmsPC4g2: msFA4bit port map (w2,b,w4,w0,co);
gmsPC4g3: ms21mux4 port map (w0,w3,clk,w1);
a <= w2;

end Structure;
```

So if you'll notice, I have 3 components, a couple signals to connect everything and such.

What I REALLY want, is for signals w3 and w4 to be SET to ground (tied to logic low, as it were), but for whatever reason, I cannot for the life of me figure out how I am supposed to do this.

FWIW I'm an EE so I'm more accustomed to seeing this from the hardware end. Also, this project specifically *has* to be done with port maps and not the behavioral stuff. Sorry about that.

Edit: The error is being thrown at lines where w3 is set to '0', w4 is set to '0000'. Double quotes do not fix this error. Moving it inside begin does not fix the error. Inside the begin set I get an "UNEXPECTED TICK" and outside the begin set I get a "UNEXPECTED IDENTIFIER". It just really doesn't want to let me decide the value of something.

Comment: do they not teach the difference between declarations and statements any more?

Comment: You can not assign value between architecture and begin.

Comment: Unexpected tick because vector literals must be enclosed between double quotes, not ticks (`"0000"`, not `'0000'`). Unexpected identifier because the two assignments must go in the architecture body (after `begin`), not in the architecture declaration (before `begin`). You randomly tried several solutions but not all: you forgot the combination double-quotes + after begin. If you try to solve all your problems with this random strategy it will take time before you learn VHDL. Books and classes are probably more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your code:

```
-- w4 <= '0';
-- w3 <= '0000';

begin
    w4 <= '0';
    w3 <= "0000";
```

Allows successful analysis, noting there are no other drivers from `w4` or `w3`.

Alternatively you can provide default values in the declarations:

```
    signal w0, w1, w2: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    signal w3: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0) := "0000";
    signal w4 : STD_LOGIC := '0';


-- w4 <= '0';
-- w3 <= '0000';
```

This also analyzes.

The default value represents the value of a signal prior to a signal assignment.

You can also supply values directly:

```
gmsPC4g1: msdff4 port map (w1,clk,w2);
gmsPC4g2: msFA4bit port map (w2,b,'0',w0,co);   -- w4
gmsPC4g3: ms21mux4 port map (w0,"0000",clk,w1); -- w3
```

This analyzes.

Or provide constant values:

```
    signal w0, w1, w2: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    constant w3: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";
    constant w4 : STD_LOGIC := '0';


-- w4 <= '0';
-- w3 <= '0000';

begin

gmsPC4g1: msdff4 port map (w1,clk,w2);
gmsPC4g2: msFA4bit port map (w2,b,w4,w0,co);
gmsPC4g3: ms21mux4 port map (w0,w3,clk,w1);
```

which also analyzes.

Notice the double quotes used in string literal values (`"0000"`). Single quotation marks (ticks) are used for character literals with graphical representation.

You are not using either package std_logic_arith nor std_logic_unisigned. Their use clauses are superfluous.